# Django include fields from AbstractUser to registration form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

**I am new to Django and need some help.**
**I am trying to include two fields into my registration form. Sow person how wonts to register can determine if he or she wants to register as majstor or korisnik. I added, into AbstractUser. Tho's fields majstor and korisnik as BooleanField.How to add optional fields in a form, sow a person can choose one of those values?**

**This is mine korisnik/model.py file:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class CustomKorisnici(AbstractUser):
    majstor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    korisnik = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,unique=True)
```

**This is mine members/forms.py file**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from korisnici.models import CustomKorisnici
from django import forms

class SingUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length= 100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length= 100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))


    class Meta:
        model = CustomKorisnici
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email', 'password1','password2')

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(SingUpForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Comment: I added to fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email', 'password1','password2','majstor','korisnik'). But person can still select both of those fields

Comment: Instead of two Boolean fields you can use an optional ChoiceField. You can create the choice field using CharField with `blank=True` to make it optional. It's optional so user can skip it, and if user wants to answer that then only one option can be selected. Later you can check if the field is populated then based on selected choice you can move on it.